# Code Elegance: Java Strings

Tags: java, string

A program that takes the first two characters of a string and adds them to the front and back of the string. Which version is better?

```
public String front22(String str) {
  if(str.length()>2) return str.substring(0,2)+str+str.substring(0,2);
  return str+str+str;
}
```

or

```
public String front22(String str) {
  // First figure the number of chars to take
  int take = 2;
  if (take > str.length()) {
     take = str.length();
 }

  String front = str.substring(0, take);
  return front + str + front;
}
```

The former strikes me as more elegant. The latter is easier to understand. Any other suggestions for improvement of either is more than welcome!

Comment: why `str.length()>2`? why not `>=`?

Comment: I downvoted this question because it does not belong on StackOverflow. You should delete this post and re-post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If elegance = minimum length, then I'd use a regex.

Comment: @Pshemo - I didn't downvote this question because it is on-topic on another site. As I stated in my comment, I downvoted it because I feel it doesn't belong on StackOverflow. The reason that I feel this way is because it is not "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" as per the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article.

Comment: Now that I re-read your comment I see it clearly. Sorry, I misunderstood it earlier. I agree that question is off-topic here but I seen many cases where people downvote/close just because there was better site for it. Will remove my comment then :)

Comment: Another approach https://ideone.com/6RPhar

Answer (score 1):

Issue with the first option, mainly because `string` is immutable. [**Edit**.] As @Pshemo correctly pointed out, my statement was unclear. Quoting @Pshemo, `"executing same substring twice is inefficient when we can reuse result from first substring"`.

Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
CharSequence seq = sb.subSequence(0,2);
sb.insert(0, seq);
sb.append(seq);
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: @Pshemo won't substring create a new string for java >= 7?

Comment: Actually I made mistake in my first comment. Didn't pay attention to fact that you used `insert` instead of `append`. Sorry for that. My point was that code like `return str1+str2+str3` is actually the same as `return new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2).append(str3).toString();`. Also yes, substring will create new String which will contain local copy of characters from original string, instead of storing reference to original array of characters. It was changed in Java 7 but I don't see how it is relevant here (if I am misunderstanding your answer could you update it and add more details?).

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, I realized that you thought I had used `append`. So, accessing the `CharSequence` returned by `subSequence` will, in essence be a soft copy that will be inserted/appended, instead of creating a bunch of new string objects.

Comment: @Pshemo I made a slight edit. Please correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: I am little confused about what you mean by "Both the options you have posted are quite bad, mainly because string is immutable". I suspect that you may wanted to say that executing same substring twice is inefficient when we can reuse result from first substring, but it isn't that obvious from that statement.

Comment: @Pshemo I see the confusion. Haha sorry for the lack of clarity. That's exactly what I meant. I made the edit. Thanks!

Comment: It was even more confusing because first version of your answer (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36703413/1) didn't actually solve that problem :)

Comment: @Pshemo Yes sir. I realized that. :)